# How to manage SEO content pages for a similar content hierarchy?

Tags: seo, duplicate-content, keywords, content

For example, we have the following search phrases in Google:

- "Best vehicle for builders?" - 200 Monthly Searches
- "Best truck for builders?" - 400 Monthly Searches
- "Best small truck for builders?" - 800 Monthly Searches

What happens if the answer and recommendation for these three questions is "truck A?" "Truck A" is the best vehicle, truck and small truck for builders.

Would you still create three separate pages, even though the content would be very similar? Is there an optimal way to handle this?

Answer (score 4):

Definitely do not create three different pages for this type of content. The content is far too similar, mostly synonyms that lead to the same answer. Best case scenario, search engines will ignore some or (even less ideal) all of these pages; worst case, your whole site gets penalized for duplicate content and for trying to engage in keyword stuffing.

Search engines today know the synonyms and intent for most words, and search traffic tends to reflect this. Did you get website hits for all three phrases? If yes, it means Google figured out that your product is one of the best results for all of them, and your pages were displayed to users searching for this info. That the last one got the most searches means that's the one to optimize for. But Google knows that a truck is a vehicle, and a small truck is still a truck and a small vehicle.

My advice would be to put this all on one page, but get a little creative with the copy. By "creative," I mean make it sound natural, rather than trying to stuff every phrase variation into the page copy.

So something like: "Truck A is the best small truck for builders who need a vehicle for smaller jobs."

Not: "Truck A is the best small truck. Buy Truck A to get the best vehicle for builders. Because Truck A is the best truck if you're a builder."

That said, remember that this content phrasing is still an experiment. Set your KPI's (from which search phrase do you get the most hits and conversions?) and when you make changes, track your KPI's, so you can make adjustments in the future (or reversals if the trend is heading in the wrong direction).

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't create multiple pages around a topic where each page is centered around a search phrase. That will look spammy and create a poor user experience.

As Henry's answer says, you can create a single page and try to use synonyms in a natural way.

Another possibility is creating pages that use a wide variety of phrases, but have the pages centered around content that users might find compelling. For example a set of pages might be titled:

- Truck A (main page)
- Truck A vs Truck B (comparison)
- Truck A vs Truck C (comparison)
- Alice's review: Truck A is the best vehicle for my construction company (user generated content)
- Bob's review: As a builder, I prefer truck A. (user generated content)
- Our opinion: Truck A's strong points (professional review)
- Truck A's best features (professional in depth review of features and accessories)
- Truck A 2023 model launched with improvements (news article)
- Truck A deals (where to buy and price comparison)
- Truck A video tour (video content)
- How to create storage compartments in the bed of Truck A (how-to content)

Having lots of content about a topic over many interesting pages gives your site depth.  Search engines will then be more likely to consider your site an authority on the subject. It will give you ways to use a variety of related phrases and synonyms in a very natural way.

Answer (score 2):

Stephen and Henry have both written great answers here. However, I disagree that the search terms (which I assume you're seeing in your query report in Search Console) don't provide sufficient evidence to warrant more than one piece of content - a "vehicles" piece could be relevant.

I would recommend 2 blog articles:

**Article 1: 2022 Best Trucks for Builders & Construction Workers**

- I couldn't find a piece that covered 2022, the latest seemed to be 2021. An up-to-date article with comparable content to the existing articles on the first page would stick out to the algorithms of Google and others.
- Organize the piece based on various makes/models of 2022 pickup trucks - I would also mention cargo vans (like Transits and Sprinters).
- Pull from Stephen and Henry's answers for the rest

**Article 2: 2022 Best Vehicles for Carpenters and General Contractors**

- While they're still "Builders" Carpenters and General Contractors aren't hauling a ton of stuff to work every day. Most carpenters are probably only bringing couple of buckets with their stuff, a saw or two, etc. But they're still around job sites so whatever they're driving should probably be a bit tough, convenient storage, etc. Growing up I was on a lot of job sites with my Dad - a lot of guys drove Jeeps, Camrys, Subarus, etc. A general contractor could be driving anything, depending on what they're doing...even a luxury sedan. In any case, neither necessarily need a "Truck".

It is clear that Google at least has a hint of the distinction (see People also ask):

[image]

An additional consideration here (and I suppose in Article 1 too) might be fuel economy, since the cost of gas in 2022 is much higher than previous years.